# ElasticSearch 6.4: Mapping with RestHighLevelClient

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Elastic are updating their docs to use the RestHighLevelClient with Java now. It also has a mapping API:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-put-mapping.html

Now how do you make a request like this with that API?

```
PUT /test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "email": {
          "type": "pattern_capture",
          "preserve_original": 1,
          "patterns": [
            "([^@]+)",
            "(\\p{L}+)",
            "(\\d+)",
            "@(.+)",
            "([^-@]+)"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "email": {
          "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",
          "filter": [
            "email",
            "lowercase",
            "unique"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "emails": {
      "properties": {
        "email": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "email"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Are you supposed to split it in two requests and use this API for the second request? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-indices-put-settings.html

Or is the RestHighLevelClient intended for high performance operations, but for initial configuration you are free to use RestTemplate (Spring) or any other normal Java Rest Client?

Comment: IMO, I prefer using the XContentFactory and then perform a PUT request using the low level client. Internally all the elastic APIs use XContentFactory to build request like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in the docs:

```
PutMappingRequest request = new PutMappingRequest("twitter"); 
request.type("tweet");
```

You can set the payload of this request using your definition as String

```
request.source(
"{\n" +
"  \"properties\": {\n" +
"    \"message\": {\n" +
"      \"type\": \"text\"\n" +
"    }\n" +
"  }\n" +
"}", 
XContentType.JSON);
```

or a Map with your properties or even the `XContentBuilder`.

With the low-level client you execute any kind of requests, including the one your are looking for.

As regards the name, I think that **HighLevel** refers to the fact that methods are provided (aka re-usability, convenience) to create the requests and one is not forced to implement the rest requests themselves. You can always use the RestTemplate. Note the HighLevelRestClient uses the **apache HttpClient** internally.

But for the code maintainability, I would choose one way to go. (Low-High level or any http-client).

from docs (Note the RestHighLevelClient is built upon the low level one.)

> The low-level Java REST client internally uses the Apache
> Http Async Client to send http requests. It depends on the following
> artifacts, namely the async http client and its own transitive
> dependencies:
>
> - org.apache.httpcomponents:httpasyncclient
> - org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio
> - org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient
> - org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore
> - commons-codec:commons-codec
> - commons-logging:commons-logging

Comment: Yeah, it's just that the PutMappingRequest works at mappings-level, so I can't go a level up in the JSON and set the settings attribute. As Technocrat Sid commented and you implied, I have to use the RestLowLevelClient or a custom Java Client, I guess....

Comment: If you say I have to use the RestLowLevelClient explicitly in your answer I will accept it in a few minutes, when I can :D

Comment: Wouldn't it be then an opinion based answer :) But yeah, I used only the LowLevelClient when I had to do many kind of different requests. The HighLevel one I have used when I only needed to implement queries.

Comment: Haha, good point. But I think it's best to use the standard that a framework provides, even if other options are legit too. Thank you

Comment: Ftr: In 6.7.2 (currently the newest version one can get on AWS), `.type()` is gone 